# Why is recursive regex not regex?

Tags: regex, recursion, pcre

I was reading through some of the responses in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression) question and saw that a few people said that recursive regular expressions were not strictly speaking regular expressions.

Why is this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

“Strictly” regular expressions describe [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). But many features, such as the usage of backreferences in the expression itself or recursion for example, can be used to write regular expressions that accept non-regular languages.

For example, the language described by

```
(a+)b+\1
```

isn't regular, as you can't force that `a` appears the same number of times before and after the `b`s. At least not in a regular language. With context-free or even context-sensitive languages, that's a completely different matter.

However, regular expressions that only use elementary things such as the various quantifiers, character classes, etc. *usually* still describe regular languages.

Answer (score 15):

All regular languages can be recognized by a *finite automaton*. A finite automaton has a finite number of states, and consequently, finite memory (hence the name). A recursive "regular" expression requires a potentially infinite stack space to do the recursion, thus it is not possible to recognize it with a finite automaton, therefore it is not regular.

Answer (score 11):

The strict definition of regular language from theoretical computer science may seem abstract with little practical benefit, but if you’re ever faced with the need to implement a state machine to recognize certain inputs, you can save yourself a lot of useless effort and hairpulling if you can prove up front that it can’t be done.

An informal way to express it is recognition of a regular language cannot require an arbitrary amount of memory. The [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) is useful for proving that a particular language (*i.e.*, a set of strings) cannot be recognized by a deterministic finite automaton.

From [*An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763714224) by Peter Linz (pg. 115, 3rd ed.):

> #### Theorem 4.8
>
> Let *L* be an infinite regular language. Then there exists some positive integer *m* such that any *w* ∈ *L* with |*w*| ≥ *m* can be decomposed as
>
> > *w* = *xyz*,
>
> with
>
> > |*xy*| ≤ *m*,
>
> and
>
> > |*y*| ≥ 1,
>
> such that
>
> > *w*<sub>*i*</sub> = *xy<sup>i</sup>z* — Eq. (4.2)
>
> is also in *L* for all *i* = 0, 1, 2, …

To recognize an infinite language, a finite automaton must “pump” or repeat some portion of its states, and that’s the function of *y<sup>i</sup>* (notation for some string *y* repeated *i* times).

Very nearly all proofs involving the pumping lemma involve proof by contradiction. On page 117, the author proves that the language *L* = { *a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>* : *n* ≥ 0 }—*i.e.*, strings of the form *aaa…bbb…* where the all-*a* and all-*b* substrings are equal in length—is not regular:

> Assume that *L* is regular, so that the pumping lemma must hold. We do not know the value of *m*, but whatever it is, we can always choose *n* = *m*. Therefore, the substring *y* must consist entirely of *a*'s. Suppose |*y*| = *k*. Then the string obtained by using *i* = 0 in Equation (4.2) is
>
> > *w*<sub>0</sub> = *a<sup>m-k</sup>b<sup>m</sup>*
>
> and is clearly not in *L*. This contradicts the pumping lemma and thereby indicates that the assumption that *L* is regular must be false.

Other examples of languages that are not regular:

- *L* = { *ww<sup>R</sup>* : *w* ∈ Σ<sup>*</sup> } — *i.e.*, palindromes
- *L* = { *w* ∈ Σ<sup>*</sup> : *n<sub>a</sub>*(*w*) < *n<sub>b</sub>*(*w*) } — *i.e.*, number of *a*s fewer than number of *b*s
- *L* = { *a<sup>n!</sup>* : *n* ≥ 0 }
- *L* = { *a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>l</sup>* : *n* ≠ *l* }
- *L* = { *a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>l</sup>* : *n* + *l* is a prime number }

It turns out that what we loosely call regular expressions are considerably more powerful: matching regular expressions with backreferences is [NP-hard](http://perl.plover.com/NPC/)!

Comment: +1. Nice :-). I hated those proofs, actually; we had to do way too many of them ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The basis of the other answers requires an understanding of the involved computation theory.  If your only exposure to regular expressions is in a programming environment, you may not realize that regular expressions are mathematical constructs, as well.  The wikipedia article on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory) may provide some background into the theoretical aspects of regular expressions.

Comment: I was just contemplating to post such an answer to complement the other two (excellent!) answers... :) +1