# PHP - BBCode parser - recursive [quote] with regex and preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, recursion, bbcode, quote

i'm making my own bbcode parser, and i've a problem when i try to do the recursive quote.

this is my code :

```
 function forumBBCode($str){
$format_search=array(
'#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]#is'
);

$format_replace=array(
'<blockquote class="quotearea"><i><a class="lblackbu" href="./index.php?status=userview&userv=$1">$1</a> wrote :</i><br />$2</blockquote>'
);

$str=preg_replace($format_search, $format_replace, $str);
$str=nl2br($str);
return $str;
}
```

what i must add/edit to do a recursive quote? 
in other words, when a quote is inside another quote...

cheers and tnx for the help

Comment: That's pretty difficult if you're new to regular expressions. Recursive regexes are tricky, so most people opt for the /e evaluation flag and actually have the regex "parser" descent into enclosed content. Anyway, first read through http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - it's a better introduction than the PHP manual.

Comment: i'll learn this guide and i'll try to make a function :) 
i'll let you know, i hope you can help me anyway! tnx!!!

Comment: I think you have two possible ways to solve that: a) loop through the content and search for opening and closing quote tags and replace them if both were found (leave the rest as visible bbcode) or b) use `preg_replace_callback()` that calls itself again if a nested quote tags was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) on the PHP manual.

This may also interest you, though it's more of a technicality: [Why is recursive regex not regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255403/why-is-recursive-regex-not-regex)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old Q but I'll post my solution anyway for ppl =]

```
$open = '<blockquote><span class="bold">Quote: </span><br />'; //the next few lines do the parsing for quote blocks. We 
        $close = '</blockquote>';                                      //have to do it outside the normal parsing arrays because that way does not allow nesting.

        preg_match_all ('/\[quote\]/i', $str, $matches);
        $opentags = count($matches['0']);

        preg_match_all ('/\[\/quote\]/i', $str, $matches);
        $closetags = count($matches['0']);

        $unclosed = $opentags - $closetags;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $unclosed; $i++) {
                $str .= '</blockquote>';
        }
//Do Quotes (nested)
        $str = str_replace ('[quote]', $open, $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/\[quote\=(.*?)\]/is','<blockquote class="darkbg"><span class="bold left">Quote: $1</span><br />', $str);
        $str = str_replace ('[/quote]', $close, $str);
return $str;
```

Peace.

Comment: You took care about unclosed tags. What if unopened ones exist as well?