# Python regexp matching or tokenizing

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have a dump of a data structure which i'm trying to convert into an XML. the structure has a number of nested structures within it. So i'm kind of lost on how to start because all the  regex expressions that i can think of will not work on nested expressions.

For example, let's say there is a structure dump like this:

```
abc = (  
        bcd = (efg = 0, ghr = 5, lmn = 10), 
        ghd = 5, 
        zde = (dfs = 10, fge =20, dfg = (sdf = 3, ert = 5), juh = 0))
```

and i want to come out with an output like this:

```
< abc >
  < bcd >   
    < efg >0< /efg >  
    < ghr >5< /ghr >  
    < lmn >10< /lmn >  
  < /bcd >  
.....  
< /abc >
```

So what would be a good approach to this? tokenizing the expression, a clever regex or using a stack?

Comment: I don't know if you're interested in theory, but there's a lot of resources and discussions regarding the regularness of regular expressions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255403/why-is-recursive-regex-not-regex.  I'm gonna bet that the reason you can't think of a way to do it in regex is that there is no way to do it in regex...

Comment: I assume that you only have the string output/dump of the structure, not the structure itself. If you had the original object/structure, it'd probably better, easier, more reliable, and less error-prone to serialize it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use pyparsing.

```
$ cat parsing.py 
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

abc = """(  
        bcd = (efg = 0, ghr = 5, lmn 10), 
        ghd = 5, 
        zde = (dfs = 10, fge =20, dfg = (sdf = 3, ert = 5), juh = 0))"""
print nestedExpr().parseString(abc).asList()

$ python parsing.py
[['bcd', '=', ['efg', '=', '0,', 'ghr', '=', '5,', 'lmn', '10'], ',', 'ghd', '=', '5,', 'zde', '=', ['dfs', '=', '10,', 'fge', '=20,', 'dfg', '=', ['sdf', '=', '3,', 'ert', '=', '5'], ',', 'juh', '=', '0']]]
```

Comment: Very nice! Could you show how to make it split by comma, so that `efg=0` and `ghr=5` will be in separate lists?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate answer that uses pyparsing more idiomatically. Because it provides a detailed grammar for what inputs may be seen and what results should be returned, parsed data is not "messy." Thus `toXML()` needn't work as hard nor do any real cleanup.

```
print "\n----- ORIGINAL -----\n"

dump = """
abc = (  
        bcd = (efg = 0, ghr = 5, lmn 10), 
        ghd = 5, 
        zde = (dfs = 10, fge =20, dfg = (sdf = 3, ert = 5), juh = 0))
""".strip()

print dump


print "\n----- PARSED INTO LIST -----\n"

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, Optional, Forward, delimitedList, Group, Suppress

def Syntax():
    """Define grammar and parser."""

    # building blocks
    name   = Word(alphas)
    number = Word(nums)
    _equals = Optional(Suppress('='))
    _lpar   = Suppress('(')
    _rpar   = Suppress(')')

    # larger constructs
    expr = Forward()
    value = number | Group( _lpar + delimitedList(expr) + _rpar )
    expr << name + _equals + value

    return expr

parsed = Syntax().parseString(dump)
print parsed


print "\n----- SERIALIZED INTO XML ----\n"


def toXML(part, level=0):

    xml = ""
    indent = "    " * level
    while part:
        tag     = part.pop(0)
        payload = part.pop(0)

        insides = payload if isinstance(payload, str) \
                          else "\n" + toXML(payload, level+1) + indent

        xml += "{indent}<{tag}>{insides}</{tag}>\n".format(**locals())

    return xml

print toXML(parsed)
```

The input and XML output is the same as my other answer. The data returned by `parseString()` is the only real change:

```
----- PARSED INTO LIST -----

['abc', ['bcd', ['efg', '0', 'ghr', '5', 'lmn', '10'], 'ghd', '5', 'zde',
['dfs', '10', 'fge', '20', 'dfg', ['sdf', '3', 'ert', '5'], 'juh', '0']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regexps is the best approach here, but for those curious it can be done like this:

```
def expr(m):
    out = []
    for item in m.group(1).split(','):
        a, b = map(str.strip, item.split('='))
        out.append('<%s>%s</%s>' % (a, b, a))
    return '\n'.join(out)

rr = r'\(([^()]*)\)'
while re.search(rr, data):
    data = re.sub(rr, expr, data)
```

Basically, we repeatedly replace lowermost parenthesis `(no parens here)` with chunks of xml until there's no more parenthesis. For simplicity, I also included the main expression in parenthesis, if this is not the case, just do `data='(%s)' % data` before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I like Igor Chubin's "use pyparsing" answer, because in general, regexps handle nested structures very poorly (though thg435's iterative replacement solution is a clever workaround).

But once pyparsing's done its thing, you then need a routine to walk the list and emit XML. It needs to be intelligent about the imperfections of pyparsing's results. For example, `fge =20,` doesn't yield the `['fge', '=', '20']` you'd like, but `['fge', '=20,']`. Commas are sometimes also added in places that are unhelpful. Here's how I did it:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

dump = """
abc = (  
        bcd = (efg = 0, ghr = 5, lmn 10), 
        ghd = 5, 
        zde = (dfs = 10, fge =20, dfg = (sdf = 3, ert = 5), juh = 0))
"""

dump = dump.strip()

print "\n----- ORIGINAL -----\n"
print dump

wrapped = dump if dump.startswith('(') else "({})".format(dump)
parsed = nestedExpr().parseString(wrapped).asList()

print "\n----- PARSED INTO LIST -----\n"
print parsed

def toXML(part, level=0):

    def grab_tag():
        return part.pop(0).lstrip(",")

    def grab_payload():
        payload = part.pop(0)
        if isinstance(payload, str):
            payload = payload.lstrip("=").rstrip(",")
        return payload

    xml = ""
    indent = "    " * level
    while part:
        tag     = grab_tag() or grab_tag()
        payload = grab_payload() or grab_payload()
        # grab twice, possibly, if '=' or ',' is in the way of what you're grabbing

        insides = payload if isinstance(payload, str) \
                          else "\n" + toXML(payload, level+1) + indent

        xml += "{indent}<{tag}>{insides}</{tag}>\n".format(**locals())

    return xml

print "\n----- SERIALIZED INTO XML ----\n"
print toXML(parsed[0])
```

Resulting in:

```
----- ORIGINAL -----

abc = (  
        bcd = (efg = 0, ghr = 5, lmn 10), 
        ghd = 5, 
        zde = (dfs = 10, fge =20, dfg = (sdf = 3, ert = 5), juh = 0))

----- PARSED INTO LIST -----

[['abc', '=', ['bcd', '=', ['efg', '=', '0,', 'ghr', '=', '5,', 'lmn', '10'], ',', 'ghd', '=', '5,', 'zde', '=', ['dfs', '=', '10,', 'fge', '=20,', 'dfg', '=', ['sdf', '=', '3,', 'ert', '=', '5'], ',', 'juh', '=', '0']]]]

----- SERIALIZED INTO XML ----

<abc>
    <bcd>
        <efg>0</efg>
        <ghr>5</ghr>
        <lmn>10</lmn>
    </bcd>
    <ghd>5</ghd>
    <zde>
        <dfs>10</dfs>
        <fge>20</fge>
        <dfg>
            <sdf>3</sdf>
            <ert>5</ert>
        </dfg>
        <juh>0</juh>
    </zde>
</abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to parse nested expressions (though it is not recommended):

```
import re

def repl_flat(m):
    return "\n".join("<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(*map(str.strip, s.partition('=')[::2]))
                     for s in m.group(1).split(','))

def eval_nested(expr):
    val, n = re.subn(r"\(([^)(]+)\)", repl_flat, expr)
    return val if n == 0 else eval_nested(val)
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/Ld4Ug)

```
print eval_nested("(%s)" % (data,))
```

#### Output

```
<abc><bcd><efg>0</efg>
<ghr>5</ghr>
<lmn>10</lmn></bcd>
<ghd>5</ghd>
<zde><dfs>10</dfs>
<fge>20</fge>
<dfg><sdf>3</sdf>
<ert>5</ert></dfg>
<juh>0</juh></zde></abc>
```