# Regex help finding special tags

Tags: php, regex

I dont know if this can be done with regex but I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
[IF Eval==1]
    Do this
[/IF]

[IF OtherEval==2]
    do this
    [IF:insideif ThirdEval==3]
        do this other stuff
    [/IF:insideif]
[/IF]
```

I want to write a regex that can give me all the `[IF` blocks and end with its corresponding `[/IF]`.

I tried `preg_match_all("'\[IF(.*?)\].*?\[\/IF{1}\]'si", $Str, $Arr)` but I only get the [IF blocks without the labels `([IF:insideif)`

I thought the capture group and using it in the `{1}` could do the trick but im not that experienced in regex.

Comment: So, you need to get `[IF Eval==1]
    Do this
[/IF]`, then `[IF OtherEval==2]
    do this
    [IF:insideif ThirdEval==3]
        do this other stuff
    [/IF:insideif]
[/IF]`, and `[IF:insideif ThirdEval==3]
        do this other stuff
    [/IF:insideif]` as output. Correct?

Comment: This sounds like a context free grammar. Unless PHP gets Perl regex capabilities, it is [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11378548/67579).

Comment: PHP *has* certain Perl regex capabilities (like defining recursive pattens).

Comment: @BartKiers: like the *balancing brackets* I guess. That's indeed worth a shot. Although one can save him/herself probably a lot of trouble by using the right tool: a real context-free grammar.

Comment: @CommuSoft, couldn't agree more. It would become some sort of ugly pattern like this: `\[IF[^\]]*](?:(?R)|(?!\[/IF[^\]]*]).)*\[/IF[^\]]*]` (test: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bjv). But that would match 2 groups (the second group containing 1 nested IF). But I think the OP is looking for a 3 separate matches (which is probably not possible in one go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the nested `[IF]`s if you use subroutines and a look-ahead together with a capturing group inside the look-ahead.

```
(?=(\[IF[^]]*](?:(?!\[\/?IF[^]]*\]).|(?1))*\[\/?IF[^]]*\]))
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4dC6/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/gpA0hN).

It matches these items in my test string:

```
[IF Eval==1]
    Do this
[/IF]

[IF OtherEval==2]
    do this
    [IF:insideif ThirdEval==3]
        do this other stuff
           [IF Eval==4]
                do another stuff
           [/IF]
    [/IF:insideif]
[/IF]

[IF:insideif ThirdEval==3]
        do this other stuff
           [IF Eval==4]
                do another stuff
           [/IF]
    [/IF:insideif]

[IF Eval==4]
                do another stuff
           [/IF]
```

Comment: Hello, maybe you can help me a bit further. Im trying to capture everything before the first [IF and everything after the last [/IF], im trying (?:.*?)(?=(\[IF[^]]*](?:(?!\[\/?IF[^]]*\]).|(?1))*\[\/?IF[^]]*\]))(.*?) but ony works for the before part, not the after and i dont know what i'm doing wrong. Also, I noticed that with your regex i don't need the :labels any more, is there any way to clean the regex to dont test for them?

Better yet, I only want to get the entire [IF  [/IF] block and i'll make a recursive function to find the ones inside because it depends on the evaluation.

Thanks

Comment: nope, it did something weird lol, I'll wait until you can check it on a desktop. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: (Removed previous comment) I think this is not the best approach. I suggest 1) getting your IF blocks, 2) replacing the 1st-level IF blocks with some token (I suggest [using a § sign and this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4dC6/2)), 3) split/explode the string. Mind that it is a mystery to me how you want to distinguish between the end of the previous and the beginning of the next IF block.