# Function for balancing parentheses

Tags: python, parentheses

I am trying to implement a function for balancing parentheses of a given math equation as a string. It should be changing the string, not just checking if it is balanced.

Because the math equation can contain trigonometric functions, I want to add `radians()` after such functions, because in Python, trigonometric functions take input as radians, while I want degrees.

So `tan(65)` becomes `tan(radians(65))`.
`cos(65) + sin(35)` becomes `cos(radians(65)) + sin(radians(35))`
`cos((30 - 10) * 2)` becomes `cos(radians((30 - 10) * 2))`

So far, what I've done is using `replace()` to replace `cos(` with `cos(radians(`, `sin(` with `sin(radians(` and the same thing goes for all the rest trigonometric functions. But the problem is, the string (which is a math equation) becomes parentheses-unbalanced.

How do I write a function to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `cos` with `cosdeg` and define:

```
def cosdeg(x):
   return cos(radians(x))
```

Or (lambda version):

```
cosdeg = lambda x : cos(radians(x))
```

And in a similar way with the other trig functions.

Comment: I like this answer as it shows a better way than what OP had already taken for granted as solution.

Comment: Very nice answer. However, in my program, the input is evaluated by the `eval()` function. For the sake of time and user-friendliness, I cannot define a new function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of an algorithm to both insert `radians(` at the proper place and keep the parentheses balanced. This will work if the parentheses are indeed balanced beforehand and if there are no unbalanced parentheses in string literals such as `len("abc(d")`. It does not seem terribly pythonic, however.

Do not just use `replace()`. Instead, use `find()` to find a usage of `cos(` or other trig function. Set a counter to zero. Then scan the string from immediately after that opening parenthesis [the `(` in `cos(`] to the right. When you encounter an opening parenthesis, increment the counter by one; when you encounter a closing parenthesis, decrement the counter by one. When your counter reaches `-1` you have found the close parenthesis for your trig function. Insert a new close parenthesis at that location, *then* insert your `radians(` just after the trig function.

Continue this until you have treated all the trig functions in your string.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach: `cos (0)` is valid but not detected (there's a space between `cos` and `(`). Probably a regular expression would be needed.

Comment: @jp48: I thought of that but the OP did not consider that possibility in his attempted algorithm. I assumed that the string has been pre-processed in some way to remove such possibilities or that he is replacing the `cos` with `cos(radians` or some such. Perhaps I should have included such details in my answer, but I decided to leave them out and call my answer "an outline of an algorithm." I am working on having the right amount of detail in my answers and I sometimes overshoot or undershoot.

Comment: @jp48: I know a little about regular expressions and I do not know how to find both the function and its paired closing parentheses. How can that be done? That would be worth a full answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Exactly. I do pre-process  the string to eliminate all the space characters.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Well, it actually requires *recursive* regular expressions, not supported by `re`; instead the `regex` module should be installed. I believe they are not actually 'regular expressions' as formally defined by theoretical CompSci. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/2180200 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/26385984/2180200 ; and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255403/2180200