# php - how to validate a regular expression itself?

Tags: php, regex, validation, filtering, user-input

I need to validate user input that might be a regular expression for filtering fields in his/her own application, how can I check the validity of that regex?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it into a dummy call to `preg_match()`, and see if it returns false (indicating an error)?

**Note::** Depending on where you intend this application to be run, I would question the decision to allow users to do this.  You could be setting yourself up for a denial-of-service attack; all a malicious user needs to do is provide an incredibly long, complicated regex string, and your server will grind to a halt.

Comment: i like your idea, i thought to implement that one but thought it was kinda bad practice, so decided to come here. thanks for the advice