# How to validate a regex with PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to be able to validate a user's inputted regex, to check if it's valid or not. First thing I found with PHP's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` constant but that doesn't do what I want since it must pass a regex to the options but I'm not regex'ing against anything so basically it's just checking the regex validity.

But you get the idea, how do I validate a user's inputted regex (that matches against nothing).

Example of validating, in simple words:

```
$user_inputted_regex = $_POST['regex']; // e.g. /([a-z]+)\..*([0-9]{2})/i

if(is_valid_regex($user_inputted_regex))
{
    // The regex was valid
}
else
{
    // The regex was invalid
}
```

Examples of validation:

```
/[[0-9]/i              // invalid
//(.*)/                // invalid
/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/       // valid
/([a-z]+)-([0-9_]+)/i  // valid
```

Comment: Can you be more explicity about what you mean by `that matches against nothing` ? It is an empty string ?

Comment: I mean nothing as no variable, I'm not passing anything to validate against the user's regex.

Comment: Sorry to come up with this issue again, but if you're `not passing anything to validate against the user's regex`, how can you validate the regexp ? You said in the question that you don't want to check the validity, so what the heck do you want to check the regexp against ?

Comment: @pinouchon: The OP wants to validate if a given string is a valid PCRE pattern (i.e.: validate delimiters, escape sequences, matching groups and so on).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747347/php-how-to-validate-a-regular-expression-itself

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: Never mind, found the solution.

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: Keep in mind that some regular expressions can be valid, but dangerous. For example: `/(.*)/e`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an idea ([demo](http://ideone.com/pXS4d)):

```
function is_valid_regex($pattern)
{
    return is_int(@preg_match($pattern, ''));
}
```

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop
>   searching after the first match.
>
> preg_match() returns FALSE if an error occurred.

And to get the reason why the pattern isn't valid, use `preg_last_error`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to write your own function to validate a regex.  You can validate it so far as to say whether it contains illegal characters or bad form, but there is no way to test that it is a working expression.  For that you would need to create a solution.

But then you do realize there really is no such thing as an invalid regex.  A regex is performance based.  It either matches or it doesn't and that is dependent upon the subject of the test--even if the expression or its results are seemingly meaningless.

In other words, you can only test a regular expression for valid syntax...and that can be nearly anything!

Comment: Of course there is such a thing as an invalid regex. Take "incomplete group structure" as an example.