# Regular Expression as part of query parameter for RESTful API

Tags: node.js, restful-architecture

I am reading/implementing a RESTful API design, where the author has stated that regex can be used in the query param as part of filtering.

For example:

```
https://example.com/users?name=/bil?li/
```

From various articles on ReDoS, I can't help to think that this is not a very good idea because I don't believe there is a sane way to do validation and whitelisting on the incoming regex. And the datastore/database could suffer heavy penalties.

So if this requirement is part of an API spec, that I have no control over, how would I safely implement this feature?

I would be using Express.js

Comment: Look at this answer of [regex validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747347/php-how-to-validate-a-regular-expression-itself)

Comment: Or even this [regex validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704857/how-to-check-if-a-given-regex-is-valid)