# Javascript regex to match a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a special regex to match a javascript regex.

For now I have this regex working:

> ```
> /\/(.*)?\/([i|g|m]+)?/
> ```

For example:

```
'/^foo/'.match(/\/(.*)?\/([i|g|m]+)?/) => ["/^foo/", "^foo", undefined]
'/^foo/i'.match(/\/(.*)?\/([i|g|m]+)?/) => ["/^foo/i", "^foo", "i"]
```

Now I need to get this regex working with:

```
'^foo'.match(/\/(.*)?\/([i|g|m]+)?/) => ["^foo", "^foo", undefined]
```

Unfortunately my previous regex doesn't work for that one.

Can someone help me to find a regex matching this example (and others too):

```
'^foo'.match([a regex]) => ["^foo", "^foo", undefined]
```

Comment: Your first regex also matches `/foo/|||`, FYI.

Comment: I literally just asked the question with a new twist. Take a look at [slak's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535865/regex-describing-a-regex-pattern#comment62561839_37535865)...

Comment: see also: [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172303/11107541)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A regular expression to match a regular expression is

```
/\/((?![*+?])(?:[^\r\n\[/\\]|\\.|\[(?:[^\r\n\]\\]|\\.)*\])+)\/((?:g(?:im?|mi?)?|i(?:gm?|mg?)?|m(?:gi?|ig?)?)?)/
```

To break it down,

1. `\/` matches a literal `/`
2. `(?![*+?])` is necessary because `/*` starts a comment, not a regular expression.
3. `[^\r\n\[/\\]` matches any non-escape sequence character and non-start of character group
4. `\[...\]` matches a character group which can contain an un-escaped `/`.
5. `\\.` matches a prefix of an escape sequence
6. `+` is necessary because `//` is a line comment, not a regular expression.
7. `(?:g...)?` matches any combination of non-repeating regular expression flags.  So ugly.

This doesn't attempt to pair parentheses, or check that repetition modifiers are not applied to themselves, but filters out most of the other ways that regular expressions fail to syntax check.

If you need one that matches just the body, just strip off everything else:

```
/(?![*+?])(?:[^\r\n\[/\\]|\\.|\[(?:[^\r\n\]\\]|\\.)*\])+/
```

or alternatively, add `"/"` at the beginning and end of your input.

Comment: I don't know by looking whether this works, but I do know that it frightens me.

Comment: `'/foo/i'.match(/\/(?![*+?])(?:[^\r\n\[/\\]|\\.|\[(?:[^\r\n\]\\]|\\.)*\])+\/(?:g(?:im?|m)?|i(?:gm?|m)?|m(?:gi?|i)?)?/)` result is `['/foo/i']`. That's not expected result.

Comment: @jules, I added parentheses in the appropriate places so that the match has the bits you expect.

Comment: @MikeSamuel All the purpose of my question was to match `'^foo'.match([a regex]) => ["^foo", "^foo", undefined]`. I know this is not a regex (cuz' there's no slash), but I want to be smart and match this one too. Do you have an idea? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jules, The second regex should match just the pattern portion without the surrounding `/`s or the flags.

Comment: "x = 2; y = x / 3; z = x/4". In this case your regex would not work

Comment: @Gor, this pattern is not meant to lex JS. It would also spuriously match in `"/./"`. JS doesn't have a regular lexical grammar, so this is not a problem with this regex. No regex will correctly split an arbitrary JS program into tokens.

Comment: You could change the flag matching to something like this: `(?:i(?!.*i)|g(?!.*g)|m(?!.*m))*` or if there are matching groups `((?:([igm])(?!.*\3))*)`, group 3 would the last flag. You may have to affix `(?=\s|$)` as well then though. The nice part is it's then really simple to add flags. e.g. `(?:i(?!.*i)|g(?!.*g)|m(?!.*m)|u(?!.*u)|y(?!.*y))*`

Comment: Oh, on second thoughts, if people want regex that matches with a string (or something) after it this: `(?:i(?!\w*i)|g(?!\w*g)|m(?!\w*m))*(?!\w)` may be more appropriate. (or `((?:([igm])(?!\w*\3))*)(?!\w)`)