# preg_replace_callback to run EXCEPT when inside first argument of .replace()

Tags: php, regex

I want to perform a php `preg_match_callback` against all single or double-quoted strings, for which I'm using the code seen on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/217356, which includes handling of backslashed single/double quotes.

```
const PATTERN = <<<'PATTERN'
~(?|(")(?:[^"\\]|\\(?s).)*"|(')(?:[^'\\]|\\(?s).)*'|(#|//).*|(/\*)(?s).*?\*/|(<!--)(?s).*?-->)~
PATTERN;

$result=preg_replace_callback(PATTERN, function($m) {
            return $m[1]."XXXX".$m[1];
        }, $test);
```

but this runs into a problem when scanning blocks like that seen in .replace() calls from javascript, e.g.

```
x=y.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

... which treats `'/g, '` as a string, with the `"');......."` as the following string.

To work around this I figure it would be good to do the callback except when the quotes are inside the first argument of .replace() as these cause problems with quoting.

i.e. do the standard callbacks, but when `.replace` is involved I want to change the `XXXX` part of `abc.replace(/\'/, "XXXX");` but I want to ignore the `\'` quote/part.

How can I do this?

See <strike>https://onlinephp.io/c/5df12</strike> ** https://onlinephp.io/c/8a697 for a running example, showing some successes (in green), and some failures (in red).
(** Edit to correct missing slash)

Note, the XXXX is a placeholder for some more work later.

Also note that I have looked at [Javascript regex to match a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843691/javascript-regex-to-match-a-regex) but this talks about matching regex's - and I'm talking about excluding them. If you plug in their regex pattern into my code it does not work - so should not be considered a valid answer

Comment: Are you sure the expected `g=g.replace(/\'g, 'XXXX');` is correct? It's missing a slash.

Comment: Good spot .. I'll fix that... if I can

Comment: I tried the following pattern with your code which seems to succeed for the provided test cases: [`\(\s*/.*?/\w*,(*SKIP)(*F)|(?|(")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(')[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')`](https://regex101.com/r/UGH5Tv/1)

Comment: Thanks BB - but I get errors with that ... see https://onlinephp.io/c/b7405

Comment: You forgot the delimiters, see [your updated demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/a21b4).

Comment: Do you want to add the answer or shall I?

Comment: I put already, glad it works :)

Comment: I've got to say - this is all black magic to me - which part of pattern excludes the ".replace" part ?

Comment: The skipped part is the left part of the alternation. Have you studied [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985) that I have included in my answer? It's very well explained there. It works similar like what's at [RexEgg mentioned as **The Trick**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): *Match what' you don't want on the left side...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to *skip* something. For skipping the *first argument* e.g.:

```
\(\s*/.*?/\w*\h*,(*SKIP)(*F)|(?|(")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(')[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UGH5Tv/2) or [your updated php demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/a21b4)

---

The pattern on the *skipped side* is very simple, you might want to [further improve](https://regex101.com/r/UGH5Tv/3) that.
Besides I used a bit more efficient pattern to match the quoted parts, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452781/5527985).

Comment: Please use 3v4l.org for your demo.  That phpsandbox has a horrible UX on mobile.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for comment! It's the updated demo from OP, I like 3v4l.org too but my favorite is tio.run because it feels lightweight and supports a whole lot of languages.

Comment: as an addition ... I've spotted I need to exclude strings that are proceeded by a `:`, e.g. `"propNm":xxxx`. Is there a simple adjustment to the regex pattern to take that into account too?

Comment: @user1432181 do you mean to exclude the quotes if the latter quote is followed by a colon [like this demo?](https://regex101.com/r/4YvQpQ/1) (I added a *lookahead* to skip if a colon appears after)