# How to get opposite of a regex to find all content outside of any kind of matching quotes (ignoring escaped quotes and the 1st arg of ".replace()"

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that works, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74576808/1432181.

```
\(\s*/.*?/\w*\h*,(*SKIP)(*F)|(?|(")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(')[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')
```

This selects any kinds of content inside matching quotes, ignoring escaped quotes, ignoring when in the first argument of a .replace() [which may be things like `.replace(/'/g, ...)`

(See https://regex101.com/r/42rHQx/1)

But how can I get the opposite of this (i.e. where it's blue in the regex101, I want it not selected - and where it was previously not selected I want it blue)?

(I need to use this in a preg_replace so that I can only replace things outside of the shown selected [*quoted*] content)

Comment: One option could be replacing the match with an empty string.

Comment: you can use the following regex to select everything that is not inside matching quotes, ignoring escaped quotes:

(?!'.*?'|".*?").*

Comment: Why not `preg_split` with this pattern of yours?

Comment: .. I want to str_replace the content that is not "quoted"... split will only show me the "blue" parts of the subject. See https://onlinephp.io/c/234c7

Comment: Try it like this `("[^"\\\/]*(?:\\.[^"\\\/]*)*"|'[^'\\\/]*(?:\\.[^'\\\/]*)*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+?(?=(?1)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/zbm5lB/1