# What's the regular expression for regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Ok, so it's late on a Wed night and this is for no good reason.  But I'd like to see one in any dialect, if it exists, just to be impressed.

Comment: Have you been imbibing numerous beverages as part of your evening so far?

Comment: Awe, come on.  No need to downvote...  :)  It's all in good fun!

Comment: +1. Good question. Self-hosting/bootstrapping/recursion is always intriguing.

Comment: A dupe, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: You would at least need an regex dialect that can cope with nested parentheses.

Comment: @Thilo not a dup as the answer is `regular expressions`

Comment: This is a programming game type question rather than a serious question, and is probably better suited for [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Rr][eE3][gG][uU][Ll][aA4][rR]\s[Ee3][xX][pP][rR][eE3][Ss5]{2}[iI1][Oo0][nN][sS5]
```