# Regular expression that matches regular expressions

Tags: regex

Has anyone ever tried to describe regular expression that would match regular expressions?

*This topic is almost impossible to find on the web due to the repeating keywords.*

It is probably unusable in real-world applications, since the languages that support regular expressions usually have a method of parsing them, which we can use for validation, and a method of delimiting the regular expressions in code, which can be used for searching purposes.

**But still I am wondering how would a regular expression that matches all regular expressions look like. It should be possible to write one.**

Comment: Here's one: `.*` don't know how to improve upon that since afaik regexes can take any individual character in any order, please correct me if I'm wrong people at large.

Comment: Secondly (and somewhat less facetiously) if you want to match regexes with anything more you'll need to match brackets which regexes can't do [see here for why]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: A regular expression can be almost anything. Could you give examples of what you think this would match and what would be excluded?

Comment: @Barmar - not all strings can be regular expressions - think of `a[[b`

Comment: That's why I said _almost_ anything.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Regular expressions are not like URLs or email addresses, where there are some common heuristics to recognize them in text.

Comment: @Barmar: I am not trying to do anything. For searching and validation, we can use different methods, as I wrote. I am just wondering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a formal proof for this, but I strongly suspect that the language of regular expressions is *not itself regular*, and therefore not subject to regular expressions¹. This would make a proper regex to represent it impossible.

Why? Well, it can be shown that a language that requires balanced parentheses such as Lisp (or, [more famously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/354577), HTML) [is not regular using the pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma):

> The proof that the language of balanced (i.e., properly nested) parentheses is not regular follows the same idea. Given *p*, there is a string of balanced parentheses that begins with more than *p* left parentheses, so that *y* will consist entirely of left parentheses. By repeating *y*, we can produce a string that does not contain the same number of left and right parentheses, and so they cannot be balanced.

Regular expressions [permit nested capture groups](http://regexone.com/lesson/12), which seem to fall into this category:

> Take the example from the previous lesson, if we wanted to capture the image file number along with the filename, I can write the expression `^(IMG(\d+))\.png$`.

In any case, this may be a better question for [the Computer Science Stack Exchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

**Edit:**

¹tomp points out that PCRE-based regular expression engines (and likely others) [are actually able to match all context-free grammars and at least some context-sensitive grammars](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html#what_can_regular_expressions_match)! That represents a *massive* difference in expressive power. Assuming the article is correct, pretty cool!

(Of course, whether these extended implementations are still "regular expressions" is up for debate. Since we're on a programming site I'll take the position that they are. On a CS site I'd probably take the opposite position!)

So it may be technically possible to represent regular expressions as a regular expression.

Even so, the task of writing a regex representing all regexes is *enormously complex*. Consider for comparison the task of validating an email address. Many resources boil this down to something akin to `[^@]+@[^@]+`, or "as long as there is only one at symbol and at least one character before and one character after it, we're good".

But have a look at this apparently [complete regex to validate RFC 822](http://ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Is it correct? Who knows. I'm certainly not going to check it.

Having seen this, I wouldn't want to try to write a regex to validate regular expressions.

Comment: According to this post [1], modern regex implementations have greater power than matching only regular languages. [1]: http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html#what_can_regular_expressions_match

Comment: @tomp, thanks for the link. I've updated my answer to reference it.

Answer (score 3):

I just coded this in a couple of minutes, so don't expect too much...still, it can match a regex  in a string.

```
^([igsmx]{1,})?\/(?=.*?(\\w|\\d|\[.*?\]|\(.*?\))).*?\/([igsmx]{1,})?$
```

It can be extended, a looooooot...