# In actionscript, how to check if a given regular expression is compiled or not using RegExp class

Tags: regex, actionscript

I'm new to actionscript, working on avm2..

One thing that I want to know is how to determine if a given regular expression is compiled or not in RegExp Class which use pcre library internally as regular expression compiler.

For example, the following has parenthesis-unmatched regular expression, which may be not compiled in pcre in RegExp class.

```
var r:RegExp = new RegExp("(a))");
```

I tried to use try-catch like the following, no exception occured.

```
try
{
    var r:RegExp = new RegExp("(a))");
} catch (e:Error) {
    trace('error');
}
```

I also tried to find solution on the Internet, there seem to be no method or properties for it.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried the exec and test methods. Very strange that no errors would be thrown. If AS3 RegExp supports recursion, this may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/172316/2788187

Comment: Great question, I just tried typing it as a literal:  `var r:RegExp = /(a))/;` and hoped for a compiler error but there wasn't any. If you have something that should match then you could "test" against it.

Comment: You could use a regex to test if its a regex :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression  AFAIK this is the best solution in AS3, since it does not tell you if a regex is not valid.

Comment: @sydd, that `RegExp` does not work in `AS3`. If you test "(\\)" it says that is `true`.

Comment: And if you test "(?:\?\:)" it says that is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/SyntaxError.html), an error in the regular expression will throw a `SyntaxError`:

> A SyntaxError exception is thrown when a parsing error occurs, for one of the following reasons:.
>
> • An invalid regular expression is parsed by the RegExp class.
>
> • Invalid XML content is parsed by the XML class.

As a subclass of `Error`, your code should have caught it, but it appears broken [in my testing](http://wonderfl.net/c/kBAD).