# Validating Regex expression provided by user as input in form text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement wherein my form I have a textbox and user can enter any regex expression. Is there a way I can validate the regex expression given by user as input in form textbox using JavaScript/Jquery

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: By validate do you mean: check to see if the regex they submitted was valid regex? Or do you mean: check to see if the regex they submitted would match the expected results?

Comment: Yes i want to check to see if the regex they submitted was a valid regex..

Comment: Call the RegExp constructor with the pattern within a try block

Answer (score 0):

Validating regex patterns  ,It will be like counting infinity because You have two things with regex

1. Validating the syntax
2. Validate it huge possibilities of test cases

Regex is not a language hence cannot be parsed by any regex so what you can do is limit your boundaries by putting constants on area covered by used regex so like you can say enter regex for email and then you can validate it against your pattern and then against couple of hard examples.

There are couple of patterns which can be used [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression) but again regex has no particular boundary ,read the discussion in the link which will state this fact and there is also something known as recursive regex which is not supported by all platforms

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval()`, but its taxing

```
var regex_from_input = '/^asd$/';
        try{
            eval(regex_from_input);
        }catch(e) {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `try - catch` user input using `new RegExp` constructor. Something like this.

```js
function validateRegExp(str){
  try{
    var re = new RegExp(str);
    console.log(re);
    return true;
    }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
    return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="validateRegExp(this.value);" />
```