# find whether a string is a regular expression or normal string in C#

Tags: c#

How to find whether a string is a regular expression or normal string in C#. I find in java and PHP but not C#. Can anyone help me please.
String testing = "Final";

I want to test whether "testing" is a regular expression or normal string.

Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean? Most normal strings can also be used as regular expressions.

Comment: string testing = "(\d{1,2})(,)(\s*)(\d{1,4})";

Comment: Indeed... I'm confused as to what you'd do in the other languages, too. Not all strings are valid regular expressions of course, but all regular expressions are also normal strings.

Comment: @Madhu: Right, that's a normal string as well as a valid regular expression.

Comment: string testing1 = "Final". Here testing contains regular expression. where as testing1 contains just a normal string.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression

Comment: So you need an expression to match expressions?

Comment: I mean i just want to find whether has any expressions or not

Comment: Why not see if you can parse it into c# `RegEx` object?

Comment: yes i just want to filter all the strings that has expressions in it

Comment: `"Final"` is a correct regular expression. `"^[^a]*$"` is a valid "normal string" if someone wanted to get fancy. You can get close but you'd have to decide what _counts_ as a regular expression yourself. What methods do you use in Java/PHP? Perhaps their docs explain what validation rules they use.

Comment: yes tried with new Regex(testing);
With always gives true because testing and testing1 both are valid regular expressions as said by Jon

Comment: Yes. you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can try by exception handling

```
private static bool IsValidRegex(string input)
{ 
   try
   {
     Regex.Match("", input);
   }
   catch (ArgumentException)
   {
      return false;
   }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can evaulate string in Regex

```
private static bool IsValidRegex(string pattern)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) return false;

    try {
        Regex.Match("", pattern);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If method returns false you can accept this string as normal string.

Comment: Seems quite hacky to me to rely on exceptions, However I dount there is a nicer approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think there could be one which is inline function but you would need to create it in every request :(
So, this is good enough ;)