# Provided string is RegExp format or not

Tags: javascript, regex

The provided string is javascript RegExp or not

Is there any kind of method that will check the provided string is javascript RegExp format or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
var isRegExp = true;
try {
    new RegExp("regexphere");
} catch(e) {
    isRegExp = false;
}

if(!isRegExp) alert("Not a valid regular expression");
```

Comment: This will work withour error for any string you provide as a parameter

Comment: @RaulRene try with an opening bracket `[` somewhere in the string

Comment: @RaulRene not true.

Comment: @UDITSONI How is it not working? Works perfectly fine for me.