# Regex string to validate specific Regex input

Tags: regex

I need to validate the a regex string as I get as parameter does not contain more than one capturing groups.

How can I do that with regex?

Tried counting occurrences of this
`\(.*?\)`

but I need to somehow add the option to not count parentheses as caputre groups:
`(:?*)`

Can anybody help me generate a better string?

I know that there are posts on validating regex by regex, but here I need specific validation for big query that does not support two capturing groups on regex_exreact.  I don't need to validate that the regex is correct.

---

**UPDATE:**.

I tried both suggestions here:
`\((?!\?).*?\)?`
`[^\\]?\([^?]`

they almost work.

Apparently, after testing, I found out that capturing group within a capturing group is valid.

for example: `^aaa \\s?(\\([a-z]+\\))?$` is valid
Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean not count _non-capturing_ groups? Maybe this `\((?!\?).*?\)`? Note that you can't use regex to fully validate a regex pattern though.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172303)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a regular expression to detect a valid regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172303/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-detect-a-valid-regular-expression)

Comment: Apparently capturing group within a capturing group is allowed.
Can this be done?

Comment: The given post does not answer my question - added reason in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Like someone commented: You can't validate a regular expression with a regular expression.

But you can do this:

```
[^\\]?\([^?]
```

This will match any `(` that is not escaped (`\(`), or is followed by a `?`.
Which is essentially any capturing group.

Comment: Thanks

This is not quite full yet

Apparently capturing group within a capturing group is allowed.

Can this be done?

Comment: This is where you have to check for matching brackets. Which is not something you want to do with a regular expression. If you want I can give it a go, but should really consider a different approach to this problem.

Comment: Can you please?

Comment: Is it limited to one nested capturing group?